# Ignoring fsevents dependency while deploying

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, fsevents

I developed a little Node.JS app using my macbook. Everything is fine and I'm going to deploy it to Heroku.

`git push heroku master` command exits with an error:

```
9045 info install fsevents@0.2.1
9046 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9047 info fsevents@0.2.1 Failed to exec install script
9048 error fsevents@0.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
9048 error Exit status 1
9049 error Failed at the fsevents@0.2.1 install script.
9049 error This is most likely a problem with the fsevents package,
9049 error not with npm itself.
9049 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
9049 error     node-gyp rebuild
9049 error You can get their info via:
9049 error     npm owner ls fsevents
9049 error There is likely additional logging output above.
9050 error System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
9051 error command "/tmp/build_531abeef-6dec-47ed-a19d-0a9181d01d8d/vendor/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_531abeef-6dec-47ed-a19d-0a9181d01d8d/vendor/node/bin/npm" "rebuild"
9052 error cwd /tmp/build_531abeef-6dec-47ed-a19d-0a9181d01d8d
9053 error node -v v0.10.32
9054 error npm -v 1.4.28
9055 error code ELIFECYCLE
9056 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Google is my friend, and helps me understanding the problem.

**fsevents** is a NPM module for Native Access to Mac OS-X FSEvents.

It's been installed on my local machine as a grunt-browserify dependency:

```
./node_modules/grunt-browserify/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
```

Heroku (linux) does not need nor support it, of course.

- How can I "exclude" this fsevents dependency from my deployment to
  Heroku?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I just removed node_modules from my deployment.